# Replace and with slash in resource file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

How can I replace the `and` with a `/` in the `.bib` file and tell biblatex/biber that now comma separate family and given names and slashes instead of ands separate authors?

So, I want to write

```
@BOOK{someBook,
    author = {Fermi, Enrico/Einstein, Albert},
    title = {Book},
}
```

instead of

```
@BOOK{someBook,
    author = {Fermi, Enrico and Einstein, Albert},
    title = {Book},
}
```

Comment: Instead of the same code, really :o)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but out of curiosity, what would you gain?

Comment: Not having to think of german law books and write an english and. It's just convenience

Comment: With some editors, you might define a shortcut to get ‘and’.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard for a german person to remember the english word *and*. The rule (or law) is that names are separated by the keyword `and`. Why change that law for a single person?

Comment: Most of the questions on se originate from a problem or desire of a single person ;)

Comment: While it is possible I would advise not to do it. It will make it difficult to share your bib entries -- e.g. if you want to ask a question here -- or to use external bib files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See biber's `--namesep` option which is specifically for this case. For German, you could, for example, use `--namesep=und` and use "und" in your .bib file. You can also use `--namesep=/` but you would need to put spaces around it in the bib file due to libbtparse parsing rules.

Comment: That did it, thanks. The argument, changing the `namesep` will make sharing difficult, got me though.

Comment: Yes it will make sharing difficult but without the `namesep` option, it is impossible even for one person ... also if others are using `biber`, they can use source mapping to replace the custom separator with the usual `and`.